# New "Timeless" badge for questions that continue to be useful

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

Wouldn't it make sense to have a badge for questions (or answers) that continue to be useful long after they are posted.

This would be questions that receive something like 500 views/week for 8 months, or 2 up-votes per week for 6 months.  This would target questions that are general, useful posts that continue to contribute to the community for a long time.

One of the main purposes of the Stack Exchange sites is that Q/A posts will serve as a sort of wiki after the question has been asked and an answer has been accepted.  This badge would encourage people to ask useful and general questions that will continue to help Googlers and the general public.

Comment: "Timeless" questions already have the huge bonus of being virtually immune to the repcap. So I'm not sure this is necessary.

Comment: Aren't the the popular, notable, famous question badges enough?

Comment: I like your motivation for this idea; I'd suggest it be applied to questions, to hopefully inspire forward-thinking there. I'm not sure answers necessarily need more encouragement in that way. A high ratio of upvotes to views might also be a good criterion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand this topic as "How improve the visibility of best answers?"

I think that badges mentioned by @Amal Murali are sufficient. But it could be interesting to make this badge page more useful. Today it's just a date-ordered page. Who does need it ?

[image]

While if we combine tag filters and vote ordering on this view it could be an interesting starting point for people who are looking for information about a tags, without specific question.

On the other hand it's like adding a number-viewed tab filter here :
[image]

Answer (score 13):

Similar badges [already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

[image]

Aren't these badges enough? I don't see the point in creating more badges for the same purpose. Good questions are already awarded badges on the basis of number of views they acquire.

Comment: Ahhh, but they do not use the word "Timeless" ^_^

Comment: Yes, that's true.  I had the idea that this would require steady views, not just a spike.  Something like consistently getting views for an extended period of time.

Comment: @SuperScript Questions that get "spikes" of 10k views are actually pretty rare. It literally has to be linked on Reddit or something. If you browse through the list of "Famous Questions", the vast majority of them are "timeless".